# Google Cloud Messaging - too many registered devices cause message fail?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Google Messaging Service to send push notifications for about 4000 devices. Now it has problem that all the devices cannot receive the notifications.

I am using PHP curl to send HTTP request to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`, I checked the response and return as `null` (no response). At first it works fine with small amount of devices (less than 300 devices at the last time I check).

Do I have to split the registered ids and send messages many times? For example It will take 10 minutes to send the notification to all the devices (400 devices at a time, sent 10 times, take 1 minute per sent)

I want to ask if there is any limitation for number of registered devices of GCM, or is there any famous problem that I am having with sending the request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send at most 1000 registration ids in a single http request to GCM server. Beyond 1000 ids, you must split them to multiple requests.